# Attach one html file in an email using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sunos, mailx

I am sending an email by using below commands by combining all the output and sending in one email. It works fine for me.

```
mailx -s "LIP Data Quality Report for $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1" -r rj@host.com rj@host.com <<EOF
Data Successfully loaded into LIP_DATA_QUALITY table

Total Items Purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`

Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`

Error Percentage: $QUERY2
EOF
```

Now I need to attach one file within the above email and that file is under `temp folder` with the name of `chart`. And while sending I need to send it as `chart.html` file.

So How can I modify my above command so that it can attach `chart` as `chart.html file` from  `temp folder` in the email.

Hope I am clear to everyone. I am running `SunOS`.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Updates:-**

If I need to add uuencode command in my shell script so it should be like below? or something else

```
mailx -s "LIP Data Quality Report for $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1" -r rj@host.com rj@host.com <<EOF
uuencode /tmp/chart chart.html
Data Successfully loaded into LIP_DATA_QUALITY table

Total Items Purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`

Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`

Error Percentage: $QUERY2
EOF
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send simple text file as attachment using HP-UX shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274325/how-to-send-simple-text-file-as-attachment-using-hp-ux-shell-script)

Comment: Composing MIME messages with Python or Perl is way easier than doing it with shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install sharutils
```

where `run.sh` is the attachment and `hello` is the message

```
(echo "hello"  ; uuencode run.sh run.sh ) | mailx -s "Testing 2" root@localhost



EMAILCONTENT="Data Successfully loaded into LIP_DATA_QUALITY table \n Total Items Purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`\n Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`\n Error Percentage: $QUERY2 \n"
(echo $MAILCONTENT ; uuencode /tmp/chart chart.html ) | mailx -s "Testing 2" root@localhost


 ### OR
FILE="/tmp/email.content"
echo -e "Data Successfully loaded into LIP_DATA_QUALITY table \n Total Items Purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`\n Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`\n Error Percentage: $QUERY2 \n" > $FILE 
(cat $FILE ; uuencode /tmp/chart chart.html ) | mailx -s "Testing 2" root@localhost
```

Comment: I just upated my question with the way I am using `uuencode command` is right or not? Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: nope that is incorrect since you are carrying out the uuencode withing a string called EOF that you are passing to it the correct way would be : (as above new content added to this post)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a more versatile mail user agent like `email` from http://www.cleancode.org/projects/email which natively manages attachements

Answer (score 0):

The least necessary change to your shell script would be

```
`uuencode /tmp/chart chart.html`
```

(the backticks to have the *command substitution* of uuencode inserted in the *here document*).